# Navigate from html page to windows 8 xaml page

Tags: c#, windows-8, webview

Prolog:
  I have c#/xaml project. In this project i have two pages (**MainPage.xaml, and SecondExamplePage**) with MainWebView on MainPage. On mainPage.xaml.cs i have simple code:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWebView.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///assets/physics/index.html");
    }
```

When user start app, he see html page(index.html) for e.g with one image, it's all.(i now, that is the wrong way, but customer want this).

What i need to do: When user clicked on image(on index.html page), **i'm need to navigate on SecondExamplePage.xaml How can i do that?** I reed about WebView.ScriptNotify and WebView.InvokeScript, but i don't understand how work this methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML page, your image tag would look something like this:

```
<img src="./image.png" onclick="external.notify('gotoPage2')" />
```

In your C# code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MainWebView.ScriptNotify += WebView_ScriptNotify;
    }

    void MainWebView_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value == "gotoPage2")
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    }
```

The [XAML Web View Control](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7) sample may help you here as well.

Comment: How can we send some parameter from html page(e.g. html page number), to Page2?

Comment: you get a string to work with so you can throw whatever you want in there and parse on the other side.  Perhaps something in URL query string format?